# Bokeh - Runserve.py fail

Tags: plot, ipython, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

After hearing Peter Wang talk about the **Bokeh** plotting environment, I had to try it.  The problem is I can't even get the examples to work because I can't get the plot server going.  I verified the install of all listed dependencies, and installed **continuumweb** (a module that is curiously absent from the list of dependencies in the Bokeh README on github).  However, I still encountered the error below.  It looks like this should come out of continuumweb, but I find no trace of such a sub-module within the repo.  Am I looking in the wrong place?  (I have not found any other instances of this exception.)

If anyone could provide some guidance, I would be grateful...

```
choct155@choct155-U46E:~/analysis/anaconda/pkgs/Bokeh$ python runserver.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runserver.py", line 3, in <module>
    from bokeh.server import start
  File "/home/choct155/analysis/anaconda/pkgs/Bokeh/bokeh/server/start.py", line 76, in <module>
    import services
  File "/home/choct155/analysis/anaconda/pkgs/Bokeh/bokeh/server/services.py", line 4, in <module>
    from continuumweb.launch_process import ManagedProcess
ImportError: No module named launch_process
Exception KeyError: KeyError(139639237560272,) in <module 'threading' from '/home/choct155/analysis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, the pip installer did not perform well here.  I just started from scratch by cloning the continuumweb repository and installing from source ('python setup.py install' in the cloned directory)...

All is well.

Comment: Yep, it's not on PyPI it seems... this worked. And btw here is the repo:

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/continuumweb

Answer (score 3):

For those who are reading this later, we've had two versioned releases since the original question, and they are all easy to install directly from PyPI via "pip install bokeh".  If you are using Anaconda, it's even easier to install via "conda install bokeh".